# R Quanstrat package add.signal function arguments (gt, lt, gte, eq, etc...)

Tags: r, quantstrat

I have a simple question but can anyone please point in the direction of online documentation that explains what "gt, lt, lte, gte" relationship arguments mean in the `add.signal` function in the `quantstrat` package?

I can't seem to find these codes broken down anywhere.

Any insight or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gt`, `lt`, `lte` and `gte` stand for `greater than`, `less than`, `less than or equal to` and `greater than or equal to`

E.g

in following code, you the parameter `arguments` takes in a list of parameters to be passed to function `sigCrossover`. What following code does is add signal to your strategy based by calling function `sigCrossover` on columns `nFast` and `nSlow` as specified in argument `columns` and it checks condition for `nFast` being less than `nSlow`

```
add.signal(strategy.st, name='sigCrossover',
    arguments = list(
        columns=c("nFast","nSlow"),
        relationship="lt"
    ),
    label='short'
)
```

Comment: Duh thanks don't know why I didn't realize that myself appreciate it!